# Key is missing from snippet, Zendesk

Tags: angular, zendesk

Converting .NET webform to Angular 14. For this line

```
<script id="ze-snippet" src="https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=12345"></script>
```

Implemented in TS:

```
ngOnInit(): void 
{
    let chatScript = document.createElement("script");
    chatScript.type = "text/javascript";
    chatScript.async = true;
    chatScript.src = 'https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=12345';  // Chrome complains here.
    document.body.appendChild(chatScript);
}
```

Chrome console got error:

> Key is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching over to [ngx-zendesk-webwidget](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-zendesk-webwidget), confirmed it's developed by Zendesk.

Answer (score 1):

The id is missing in the TS implementation you presented. Adding it should be sufficient to fix it.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    let chatScript = document.createElement("script");
    chatScript.type = "text/javascript";
    chatScript.id = "ze-snippet"; //add this line
    chatScript.async = true;
    chatScript.src = 'https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=12345'; 
    document.body.appendChild(chatScript);
}
```